# How to prove that $\tan \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta \right) = \cot \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

I am asked to simplify the following expression:

$$\tan \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta \right)$$

The book gives me the answer $\cot \theta$ but, when I try to derive that formula using

$$\tan \left( A \pm B \right) = \frac{\tan A \pm \tan B}{1 \mp \tan A \cdot \tan B}$$

I get $\tan \frac{\pi}{2}$ as one of the terms (which is undefined).

$$\tan \left( A \pm B \right) = \frac{\tan A \pm \tan B}{1 \mp \tan A \cdot \tan B} = \frac{\tan \frac{\pi}{2} - \tan \theta}{1 + 0 \cdot \tan \theta}$$

How do I proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: Draw a right triangle. Mark sides and the angles. Use trig defn of tan and cot.ratios.

Answer (score 4):

The formula for $\tan(A\pm B)$ is obtained by dividing the formula for $\sin(A\pm B)$ by the one for $\cos(A\pm B)$, cancelling a factor of $\cos A\cos B$ from each to obtain the usual expression. As this is an illegal division by $0$ if $A=\frac{\pi}{2}$, it's easiest just to go back to the tangent's definition, viz.$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)}=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=\cot\theta.$$

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways one can play with this type of problems.

Here is one:

$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta \right) =\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta \right)  }{ \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta \right)  }$

But

$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta \right)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cos\left(\theta \right)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\sin\left(\theta \right) =1\cos(\theta)-0\sin(\theta)=\cos(\theta)$

and

$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta \right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cos\left(\theta \right)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\sin\left(\theta \right) =0\sin(\theta)+1\sin(\theta)=\sin(\theta)$

Therefore

$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta \right) = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}=\cot(\theta)$

Answer (score 0):

$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)}=\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2} \cos\theta-\cos\frac{\pi}{2} \sin\theta}{\\cos\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\theta+\sin\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\theta}=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=\cot\theta.$